# date error from an express server with mysql2

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

Good morning all,
I have a problem with the return of sql request from my server on express nodejs
I go through the mysql2 package (or msql c is the same)
in my mysql database the recorded values ​​are correct

ex to mysql

```
dateValidation
 1. 2020-09-17
 2. 2020-08-28
```

dateValidation : it is a DATE type column
but in express when I make a request it sends me back every date -1 day

```
app.get('/clients', (req, res) => {
  const table = 'client';
  connection.query(`select  *  from ${table} where idClient =3 or idClient = 7`, (err, rows) => {
    console.log('retour sql get clients', err, rows);

    if (err) {
      res.send(err);
    } else {
      res.send(rows);
      // res.send(rows);
    }
  });
});
```

here is the answer displayed in a console.log

```
dateValidation: "2020-08-27T21:00:00.000Z"
```

I don't understand and I am stuck, if anyone has already encountered this problem or can help me
thank you

Comment: check with the timezone of mysql set it to UTC

Comment: thanks for your return
but my server and my sql base run on the same machine and I also develop the frontEnd part locally
I don't understand why I don't have the same result